# Drop in Replacement for strtotime() in PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I currently have the following code

```
$TimelineEvents[$i]["Date"] = date("F j, Y", strtotime($Date));
```

Which works just fine... Until you want to store a date before Jan 1 1970.

Being that I'm making a timeline, this is rather important functionality. Whats a replacement function I could use?

Thanks
Danny

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`DateTime` class](http://php.net/DateTime) instead:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime($Date);
$TimelineEvents[$i]["Date"] = $dateTime->format('F j, Y');
```

Comment: Fantastic, very similar to @Tim Cooper 's answer, but with compatibility with versions of PHP below 5.3 :)

Comment: @DanTonyBrown: Yeah, PHP is frustrating sometimes :(

Comment: **Note to self:** For standard formats understood by `DateTime` you don't need to create from a format as shown in [Tim Cooper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8966081/1071413). That's the essential difference between the two.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/Datetime) class, which will meet your needs:

> These functions allow you to get the date and time from the server where your PHP scripts are running. You can use these functions to format the date and time in many different ways.
>
> The date and time information is internally stored as an 64-bit number so all imaginable dates (including negative years) are supported. **The range is from about 292 billion years in the past to the same in the future**.

Example:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $Date);
$TimelineEvents[$i]["Date"] = $date->format("F j, Y");
```

Comment: My original data is an MySQL Date type. E.g. 2012-12-12. Can you show me some example code please?

Comment: Damn, getting this error - Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::createFromFormat() in /hermes/web05/b244/moo.worldwidelighthouses/Timeline.php on line 43. Looks like my host doesn't support this function.

Edit: Any others with similar compatibility issues see above answer.